# Export table with php

Tags: php, button, export-to-csv

Is possible in a webpage create a button  that export a specific table with PHP?

Example: I click the button "Export Contacts" and this call a function that return me a .csv file of the table "contacts", for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple way to export the data to csv file. You can use this.

```
<?php

$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

Here is the link http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.fputcsv.php